# django rest framework m2m post

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have been getting an error while posting to one of my endpoints. The error text is:

> `"<Customer: person@example.com>"` needs to have a value for field `"customer"` before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

The customer model is set up as having an m2m relationship with the address model, with the addition of blank/null/default=None to make it optional.

If in the serializer I comment out the billing addresses field, my post succeeds and a new customer is created.

I've tried several payloads where I specify the billing addresses as `null`, `[]` and `""` to no avail.

Models

```
class Customer(TimeStamped):
    # required
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    has_agreed_to_terms = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ## extras
    # system id
    user = models.OneToOneField('vauth.User', related_name='customer', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    # email preferences
    subscription_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    unsubscribed_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    email_frequency = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default='Weekly')
    # addresses
    billing_addresses = models.ManyToManyField('common.Address', related_name='billing_addresses_set', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    shipping_addresses = models.ManyToManyField('common.Address', related_name='shipping_addresses_set', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    # time stamps
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
    first_purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None, db_index=True)
    last_purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None, db_index=True)
    # purchases
    number_of_purchases = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # braintree
    braintree_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

Serializers

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='user-detail', required=False)
    billing_addresses = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='address-detail', required=False)
    # shipping_addresses = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='address-detail', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = (
            'url', 'id', 'email', 'has_agreed_to_terms', 'user', 'billing_addresses', #'shipping_addresses',
            'subscription_type', 'unsubscribed_date', 'email_frequency',
            'date_joined', 'first_purchase_date', 'last_purchase_date', 'number_of_purchases', 'braintree_id',
        )
```

Comment: It is a bit weird that you get the error for the 'customer' field .. Are you sure that the problem is with the billing-addresses?

Comment: This is an example - it's happening wherever M2M fields are used. Another example is the User <-> Group relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Since the version number was never specified, I'm going to assume this issue was happening on a version of DRF before they fixed the order that many-to-many relationships were created.

**In Django REST Framework 3**, you won't see this issue as DRF no longer automagically handles related fields. You must implement the creation and saving of related objects, which allows you to fix issues like this by created the related fields before creating the main one, and not the reverse which triggers this issue.

**In Django REST Framework 2**, in 2.3 or other, the order that objects are created has been improved so many-to-many objects are associated after the main object is created.